# pstricks-doi package conflict?

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, doi

The following does not work:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}

\begin{document}
  hello world
  \begin{pspicture}(1,1)
    \psline(0,0)(1,1)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

However, loading the `doi` package after `pstricks` does:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{doi}

\begin{document}
  hello world
  \begin{pspicture}(1,1)
    \psline(0,0)(1,1)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Why? Particularly, are there any caveats that I should be aware of? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`doi.sty` depends upon `hyperref`.  It is generally recommended that `hyperref` be the last package you load because of the way it redefines various macros (in order to get hyperreferencing to work).  So, this is mostly a similar case where the commands needed to get `pstricks` to work under `pdflatex` are also redefined by `hyperref`.

You might want to check out ["Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/22413) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf\usepackage{doi}\fi
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
...
```

Then `doi` is only loaded when running `pdflatex`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's happening here.  If I run `pdflatex -shell-escape` on your MWE, everything works fine.  But if I run `pdflatex -shell-escape` on a file without the package `ifpdf` and without `\ifpdf...\fi` wrapper, then I get postscript errors.  If I'm using `pdflatex` why should it matter whether I wrap the call to the package in `\ifpdf...\fi` or not?

Comment: you get the wrong driver for `hyperref` when running `latex` to ceate the image.

Comment: I am confused as well—what do we achieve by loading the `doi` package only when using `pdflatex`? I asked my question with the goal of using both the `doi` and `pstricks` packages simultaneously (and thus understanding the apparent conflict between them).

Comment: @Arman: you do not understand what exactly the option `[pdf]` does! It loads the package `auto-pst-pdf` which itself runs in the background `latex` to create a PDF image which then is used when running `pdflatex`, instead of the `pspicture` environment